# Put an <h1> linked to a css style sheet inside an html table also linked to a css style sheet

Tags: html, css

So I have a very basic question that I can not seem to figure out. I have been working on a website for awhile and I am having trouble with this basic string of code.

I want to put a `h1` that is linked via the id markup inside of a standard one cell HTML table that is also linked via id to a CSS style sheet. The problem is when I do this, it always messes up my CSS. What can I do to fix this? Below are the html AND CSS because I am running it as an inline style sheet for simplicity purposes.

```css
#headingone {
  color: #34bcb8;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Cornerstone;
  font-size: 6.25em;
  padding-top: 3em;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
}

#tableone {
  width: 1440px;
  height: 900px;
  border: 2px solid;
  position: relative;
  top: ;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableone">
  <tr>
    <th id="cell one"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
<h1 id="headingone">Lost in Paradise</h1>
```

Comment: you opened a 'tr' and where is closed? the 'h1' is not inside the table...

Comment: in the code you have provided the h1 is not inside the table. What do you mean it messes up the css?

Comment: Your question is **very unclear**. Are you asking if you can insert the `h1` into the table cell (`td`) via CSS? If true, you cannot. Just place the `h1` in the table cell.

Comment: perhaps your css is messed up because you dont have `tr` closing tags when you insert the `h1` inside the table

Comment: @threeFatCat that won't fix _"whatever"_ the problem is. Today's browsers are smart enough to fix such omissions. Not that you shouldn't close your tags, lol.

Comment: Are you wanting to overlay the `h1` on top of the table?

Comment: Yeah, I just now saw that. I knew it was something syntax based. Just a dumb thing I never saw. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just a dumb mistake with the syntax. I never put the h1 inside of the table. It just looked full because of the id. :/

Comment: ID's cannot be two or more words it must be a single word. CLASSES however can have multiple so watch out for that too. Styling might not work for that

Comment: You mean it looks full because you told the table to be `width: 1440px;
  height: 900px;`. That is, it was _"full"_ because that's the way _you_ styled it.